# Set stroke blur for VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is there any way to set a blur for the stroke lines in a VectorDrawable, other than drawing it twice with different strokewidths? Can I extend VectorDrawable and modify its paint?

Comment: only via libs like: https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat or (@Deprecated) https://github.com/telly/MrVector, open VectorDrawable.java and ^F strokePaint (you should find something interesting in private static class VPathRenderer)

Comment: @pskink I tried out vector-compat, but I couldn't get it to work. Do you have any pointers to where I might find other custom implementations? Sorry for being late, this is a hobby of mine only, so not much time :)

Comment: you have to implement it by yourself, see how `setAlpha` is done: they use `mVectorState.mVPathRenderer`, the same field you should use to set the `BlurMaskFilter` of `VPathRenderer.mStrokePaint`